# How to escape underscores in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

If I want to select strings with underscores using Oracle SQL Developer, how do I have to escape those?

I tried:

```
name like '%_%' 
name like '%'_%' 
name like '%\_%'
```

but none of this helped.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need to use the explicit [`escape`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/Pattern-matching-Conditions.htm#SQLRF52142); in this way you can decide a character to use for escaping and then use it in your `LIKE`.

For example, here I use the `'!'` to escape special characters:

```
select str
from (
        select 'a_b' str from dual union all
        select 'ab'      from dual
     )
where str like '%!_%' escape '!'
```

gives

```
STR
---
a_b
```

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: if you're adding an order by, then the order by clause comes after the escape clause.

Comment: @anjanb - Yeah, that makes sense, `escape` is part of the `like`, not the `where` or the `select`, whereas the `order by` is part of the `select`.

Answer (score 6):

Oracle [suggests](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-D2124F3A-C6E4-4CCA-A40E-2FFCABFD8E19) the code below which workded for me:

```
SELECT last_name 
    FROM employees
    WHERE last_name LIKE '%A\_B%' ESCAPE '\'
    ORDER BY last_name;
```

Comment: this works, just pointing out a caveat when using \ to escape. A few editors cannot handle \' for syntax highlighting, most notably notepad++. It does not treat `\'` as ending of a string because it thinks it was really escaped so it shows the text until the next `'` as string

Comment: Also,  \  may itself conflict with Windows path separators  - I ended up using   !